# PHP custom value in json_encode

Tags: php, json

I have this code for print result for PHP `json` output:

```
$value = array();
$return_arr = array();
$row_array = array();
$fileName = Access::FETCH("SELECT  name ,id FROM " . TAGS . " GROUP BY name ORDER BY name ASC");
foreach($fileName as $key => $value)
    {
    $row_array['id'] = $value['id'];
    $row_array['text'] = $value['name'];
    $rows2[] = $row_array;
    }

$ret = array();
echo json_encode($rows2);
```

result is:

```
[{"id":406,"text":"404"},{"id":405,"text":"tag1"},{"id":404,"text":"tag3"},{"id":401,"text":"tag4"}]
```

But in action i see id value not Between `""`(example:`"id":406`) i need to this format for `json_encode`:

`{"id":"405","text":"tag1"}`

How do create this?!

Comment: why does it matter? `405` is an int, `"405"` is a string... and ids are generally going to be ints.

Comment: If you do `SELECT id, name AS text ...` then you do not have to copy the values into a temporary array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you write your query slightly differently then it appears that you do not have to copy the values into a temporary array:

```
$fileName = Access::FETCH("SELECT id, name AS text FROM " . TAGS . " GROUP BY text ORDER BY text ASC");
json_encode($fileName);
```

In other words, `name AS text` just changes the key at the source, so to speak.

As for the integer not being a string. Before you do anything you should consider if it even matters. If it does, then correcting it is as simple as just casting them to strings:

```
$row_array['id'] = (string) $value['id'];
```

Or if you use my suggestion of the SQL query then you can just loop over the data and cast it, in place:

```
foreach ($fileName as & $value) {
    $value['id'] = (string) $value['id'];
}
json_encode($fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need numeric data to be represented as a string all you have to do is explicitly cast it to a string prior to calling json_encode like this:

```
$row_array['id'] = (string)$value['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert $value['id'] to string should help:

```
$row_array['id'] = (string)$value['id'];
```